# python No module named ujson, while it's already installed

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, redhat, ujson

I've installed ujson using command `pip install ujson`
and when I've tried to run my python project it returns
ImportError: No module named ujson

- OS version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
- Python version: Python 2.7.6
- pip list: ujson (1.35)

Any help please?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python on your machine? e.g. 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: No, I just have python 2.7

Comment: @Joseph i guess i have 2 python versions, 2.6 and 2.7. What should I do? I get the same error

Comment: Common problem, you installed the module on one version of python, but are trying to run it on the other. Make sure you are installing the module on the python version you wish to run it on :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the PYTHONPATH variable is empty, and when I added the path to the variable it works.

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
```